# Error when tryig to login to account with gd.py

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm trying to login with [this](https://pypi.org/project/gd-py/) library of python. Here is code what I tried.

Python

```
import gd

def _session_(username, password):
    try:
        client = gd.Client()
        client.login(username, password)
        
        if client.is_logged_in():
            print("Logged in successfully!")
        else:
            print("Login failed.")
        
    except gd.HTTPError as http_error:
        print("An HTTP error occurred:")
        print(http_error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "username"
    password = "password" 

    _session_(username, password)
```

And then when running this I'm getting two messages in the console. First, `Login failed`. Second, `WARNING:root:Login failed`.

I'm using Python 3.7.

Then I tried to log everything and update code too. For more clarity:

Python

```
import gd
import logging

logconfigclient = input("Logging lib config: ")

if logconfigclient.lower() == "true":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='session_info.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    print("Logging enabled")
else:
    print("Logging disabled")

def _session_(username, password):
    try:
        client = gd.Client()
        client.login(username, password)
        
        if client.is_logged_in():
            print("Logged in successfully!")
            
            logging.info("Session saved to %s")
        else:
            print("Login failed.")
            logging.warning("Login failed.")
        
    except gd.HTTPError as http_error:
        print("An HTTP error occurred:")
        print(http_error)
        logging.error("An HTTP error occurred: %s", http_error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "username"
    password = "password" 

    _session_(username, password)
```

After adding log function, I usually get error and error in log file `2023-08-09 20:41:55,405 - WARNING - Login failed`.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it to:

Python

```
import gd
import logging
import asyncio

logconfigclient = input("Logging lib config: ")

if logconfigclient.lower() == "true":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='session_info.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    print("Logging enabled")
else:
    print("Logging disabled")

async def async_main():
    name = "username"

    password = "password"

    client = gd.Client()

    try:
        await client.login(name, password)  # login

        print(f"Logged in with password: {password}")
        logging.info(f"Logged in with password: {password}")

    except gd.LoginFailed:
        print(f"Login failed with password: {password}")
        logging.error(f"Login failed with password: {password}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(async_main())
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` your `client.login()`

```py
if logconfigclient.lower() == "true":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='session_info.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    print("Logging enabled")
else:
    print("Logging disabled")

def _session_(username, password):
    try:
        client = gd.Client()
        await client.login(username, password)
        
        if client.is_logged_in():
            print("Logged in successfully!")
            
            logging.info("Session saved to %s")
        else:
            print("Login failed.")
            logging.warning("Login failed.")
        
    except gd.HTTPError as http_error:
        print("An HTTP error occurred:")
        print(http_error)
        logging.error("An HTTP error occurred: %s", http_error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "username"
    password = "password" 

    _session_(username, password)
```